# Auto Generate flat file (comma separated)

Tags: list, file

My Requirement is as below
I have one share point list(L1) in SharePoint 2013.
When I Update the list item(one record in list) , I should Auto Generate flat file (comma separated) with file content as updated item record.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create event receiver for that.

However, the task looks quite strange. What is the reason you need a file for any change? Version control? If so, then did you consider using built-in versioning for that?

**UPDATE1**. As I understand from your comment, you need to keep other system with up-to-date info from SharePoint, so you have the following ways:

1. Load data from SP on-demand from the system. You can do it using SharePoint APIs (REST, CSOM, SSOM, etc). I mean, when you need this data from SP you can just load all the necessary data you need. It can work for small lists.
2. If you have a lot of data, you can create caching on the target system and update only necessary items in the cache by getting notification from SP. So, you create an [event receiver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx) in SP that passes changed item id to the target system and it updates only this item, or you can pass all the item data with this request. Also, you can create and update the file using this event receiver. Which way is simpler, depends on the target system.

**UPDATE 2.** If you can't use Visual Studio, you can try to create a workflow which will start on item update. In this workflow you can call some WebService to notify about changes. Unfortunately, as far as I remember, where are no built-in possibility to create a file with the content of the item in native SharePoint Workflows. There are some in Nitex Workflows, but as far as I understanf, you don't have it. Unfortunately, I don't know the way to create file without using VS if the workflow approach doesn't work for you.

Comment: File generated on update will be used by other system , to keep it updated with the entries changed in share point list

Comment: Added update 1.

Comment: Hi Mikhail , Thanks for your answers. creating a file mentioned in 2nd Option is the one which i am looking for.. I understand that to create event receiver  , i need Visual Studio . But is there a way without Visual Studio?

Comment: Added update 2.